# Print Webform reference in custom view display

Tags: theming

On our D8 site we have a content type with a webform reference field `field_reference_webform`.
We then created a view with a custom views display style plugin for above content type that uses the webform reference field `field_reference_webform`.

What we want to achieve is to print the webform field in our custom view display style directly via views-view-our-display-plugin.html.twig.

The contents of our Webform reference field, however, wouldn't print. We tried to print it with below code:

```
{% if rows|length %}
{% for row in rows %}
{{ row._entity.field_reference_webform }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Instead we get the following error:

```
Object of type Drupal\webform\Plugin\Field\FieldType\WebformEntityReferenceFieldItemList cannot be printed
```

We cannot figure out what we got wrong.

We are on Drupal 8.6.2 using Webform 8.x-5.0-rc22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance it would seem you need to render this webform yourself in a preprocess function and then pass it to twig. You are trying to access the entity object using row._entity.field_reference_webform which is protected from outside access. However views should already be rendering this webform. I think maybe your template file is just setup wrong. All you have done is create a view, and put a template file for it in your theme correct?

For row level output, if your display is setup as unformatted list, your views twig file should be named:

```
views-view-unformatted--our-display-plugin.html.twig
```

and the basic code inside it should be:

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Just use {{ row.content }} which should have the rendered webform in it already.

If that doesn't work perhaps we need more information on what exactly youre trying to create a template file for. The view container, the row level, or the field level.

Comment: Thanks Matt. We elaborated on your answer and were able to solve it with your answer. I have posted the full implementation below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Matt's answer we could solve the problem as follows:

In custom_view_format.theme.inc we implemented a preprocess function:

```
function template_preprocess_views_view_sunlime_custom_view_format(&$variables) {
// View options set by user.
$options = $variables['view']->style_plugin->options;

$rows = $variables['rows'];

if($rows && sizeof($rows) > 0){
  $idx = 0;
  foreach($rows as $row){

  // We need to preprocess the referenced webform object to output it as desired in the twig template
  $webform = $row->_entity->field_candidate_status_client[0];

  // Get the machine name from the referenced webform data
  $webform_machinename = $webform->target_id;

  // Init the webform object with the given machine name
  $my_form = \Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::load($webform_machinename);


  // Generate the output from the generated webform object

  $output = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                   ->getViewBuilder('webform')
                   ->view($my_form);

  // Set this output into a custom variable so it can be accessed in the twig file
  $variables['sl_webform'][$idx]['field_candidate_status_client'] = $output;

  $idx++;
  }
 }
}
```

Then he printed the webform field in the twig template like below:

```
<div class="col col-lg-6">
  {# Access the rendered webform from our own variables array - see docroot/modules/custom/custom_view_format/sunlime_custom_view_format.theme.inc #}
  {{ attribute(sl_webform,idx).field_candidate_status_client }}
</div>
```